# How do I simulate a keypress so that SDL will pick up on it

Tags: python, linux, sdl

I have been trying to find a method to simulate a keypress from python, it works when sending it to an x server, It can type in any part except it seems SDL,I am trying to send keypresses to mupen64plus, xdotools doesn't work, xsendkey doesn't work, uinput python module doesn't work.

I can send them to the desktop (ie terminal or gedit) it's just not picking up on the keypresses inside mupen - I think it has got to do with SDL reading /dev/input/

Does anyone have any pointers, is there anyway I can implement this in python, I haven't been able to find a way to simulate hardware keypresses either.

Comment: My OS is linux mint 17.3

Comment: You probably need to use `uinput` or something. As I understand, this will be close/equivalent to hardware/kernel-level. Thus it may also need to be done as superuser. There is a Python module for it, but without updates since the year this question was posted. The C/C++ example codes don't look terribly complicated, but I haven't been able to find any other standard tools for it.